# Parse csv as json using Groovy dynamically in Jmeter

Tags: json, loops, csv, groovy, jmeter

I have csv

```
name,capital,zone,code,address,city,zip,state,phone,email
Test City,false,America,us,Address line 2,New York,10002,NY,(+1) 111-111-1112,pteset@email.com
```

What I do

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def json = new JsonBuilder()

json {
    name vars.get("name")
    capital vars.get("capital")
    zone vars.get("zone")
    code vars.get("code")
     address vars.get("address")
     city vars.get("city")
     zip vars.get("zip")
     state vars.get("state")
     phone vars.get("phone")
     email vars.get("email")
}

sampler.addNonEncodedArgument("",json.toPrettyString(),"")
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
```

But csv could consist with multiple amount of rows and not every time a need all rows from csv

So, I need some variable which will be set some counter for loop, read counter=rows from csv and return me JSON

Try to found solution here, but always have troubles with syntax while Im noob in Groovy(

As result, it should be 1 request, 1 payload, with multiple items=rows from csv

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: @daggett In existed example of code need to add some variable which will be set some counter for loop, read counter=rows from csv and return me JSON. As result, it should be 1 request, 1 payload, with multiple items=rows from csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to achieve this using CSV Data Set Config, you will have to parse the CSV file programmatically, something like:

```
def rows = 2 // how many rows you need to collect from the CSV

def entries = []
1.upto(rows, { index ->
    def values = new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines().get(index).split(',')
    def entry = [:]
    entry.put('name', values[0])
    entry.put('capital', values[1])
    entry.put('zone', values[2])
    entry.put('code', values[3])
    entry.put('address', values[4])
    entry.put('city', values[5])
    entry.put('zip', values[6])
    entry.put('state', values[7])
    entry.put('phone', values[8])
    entry.put('email', values[9])
    entries.add(entry)
})

def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(entries)
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Because if I put this code in JSR223 PreProcessor, request payload is empty

Comment: I don't know where you copied and pasted "your" code from, but if you're going to use my - you need to copy paste `sampler.addNonEncodedArgument("",json.toPrettyString(),"")` and `sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)` to the bottom as well. If there are still problems - check [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) for any Groovy-related errors

Comment: Tnx u so mush, now it works for me))
One more question, if I will need to prepare array in array, for example,
{
"name": John,
"surname":Smith,
"address": 
[
"city": New York,
"street": first street
]
...
}
Could u pls provide example of entry.put format?

Answer (score 0):

## Convert the CSV to a list of maps & pass it to JsonBuilder

You need to grab the CSV field names, from the header, then iterate through the CSV data lines.

In the exampe below I convert each line to a map then push the map into a list. i.e. the list will contain one map for each non-header row. If you have 10 lines + a header then the list will contain 10 maps.

After that it's easy, as JsonBuilder can create Json from a list of maps.

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

File csv = new File( 'ParseCsvAsJson.csv')

def lines = csv.readLines()

def header = lines[0]
def fieldNames = header.split(/,[ ]*/)
def mappedLines = []

lines[1..-1].each { line ->
  def mappedLine = [:]
  def fields = line.split(/,[ ]*/)

  fields.eachWithIndex { value, index -> 
    String name = fieldNames[ index ]
    mappedLine[ name ] = value
  }
  mappedLines << mappedLine
}

def builder = new JsonBuilder()
builder {
  json builder( mappedLines )
}

println builder.toPrettyString()
```